# Struts2 url problem

Tags: jsp, url, struts2, action

I am writing a struts2 application and to access the system the users has to login. The action I have works correctly and the system works fine but after the action returns "success" it forwards to the "welcome.jsp" page but the url ends with "login.action" . For the purpose of refreshing the page, I need the url to end with "welcome.jsp". How can I achieve this without using javascript to change the url manually? Thank you very much.

This is the action tag in my struts.xml file...

```
<action name="login" method="authenticate" class="LoginAction">     
         <result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: I assume you're adding something to the sesssion to show the user is logged in? If so have the "LoginAction" class check to see if this session attribute is set, and if the user is logged in return "success". To do this easily have "LoginAction" implement SessionAware, from there it's pretty straight forward. (Although you should figure out how to refactor your solution with interceptors, but one step at a time). This does not change the url as you requested but it will make the refresh issue go away and thus the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every URL in a properly designed action-based application should point to the dispatching servlet/filter (i.e. end with .action in your case), and never directly to a JSP. That's what the action pattern of action-based frameworks like Struts is all about.

To do what you want to do, you should not forward to the welcome.jsp after the login is sucessful. You should instead redirect to the welcome.action action, which would then forward to the welcome.jsp. See http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/redirect-action-result.html for details. And see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get for explanations on the Post/Redirect/Get pattern.

Comment: +1 The requirement shows a misunderstanding of Struts2 (and MVC) fundamentals.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I think there was a misunderstanding about what I was trying to achieve. In the system that I am making (a game) there is a welcome page where there are some fields that are queried from the database such as number of turns remaining and money etc. I needed the user to be able to refresh the page to update the static fields. I do understand the concept of MVC and realize that what I was trying to do is not following standard procedure. This being said, I would like to point out that the solution to my problem is to make the static fields dynamic. Thank you